# Troubleshooting Case Sharing for Communities

Tags: sharing

I have cases that are visible to a community user, the sharing reason says Account Sharing. I look at the Account and there is no sharing entry for that user, plus I see no groups or roles that the community user falls into. I have recalculated both Account and Case sharing.

The contact associated with the user is not a contact for any cases on the account and the contact belongs to a different account. (It used to belong to the same account as all the cases, but that was changed recently.)

Any ideas how I can find the reason this user can see these cases?

Edit: I should add that this is a Customer Community Plus User

Comment: Does this link help at all? http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/17585/visibility-of-cases-for-community-end-users/49272

Comment: Interesting link, but it seems more focused on enablement, rather than forensics.

Comment: Link doesn't help, unfortunately.